# Devise omniauth(oauth) sign_in, and sign_up path setting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, devise

I want to separate my oauth redirect paths. One is for facebook and google(`register/info1`), the other is for twitter(`register/info2`).

1. My users go to `register/info(1/2)` pages, when they sign up first time.
2. After users sign up and sign in next time, they go to `home/main`, instead of `register/info(1/2)`

   But `after_sign_up_path_for` method does not working in  `omniauth_callback_controller`. So, Users always go to `register/info(1/2)`.
   Currently, I set my `omniauth_callback_controllers.rb` like this.

> class User::OmniauthCallbacksController  <
>   Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController

```
   def self.provides_callback_for(provider)
     class_eval %Q{
       def #{provider}
         @user = User.find_for_oauth(env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)
         if @user.persisted?
           sign_in_and_redirect @user, event: :authentication
         else
           session["devise.#{provider}_data"] = env["omniauth.auth"]
           redirect_to new_user_registration_url
         end
       end
      }
  end


  [:twitter, :facebook, :google_oauth2].each do |provider|
    provides_callback_for provider
  end



  def after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
      auth = request.env['omniauth.auth'] 
      @identity = Identity.find_for_oauth(auth)

      @user = User.find(current_user.id)
      if @user.persisted?
        if @identity.provider == "twitter"
          register_info2_path
        else
          register_info1_path
        end
      else
        home_main_path
      end
  end
```

If you have any ideas or related documents, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can set the callback path per strategy in the omniauth.rb initializer:

for example:

```
Rails.application.config.middleware.use OmniAuth::Builder do
    provider :facebook, "app_id", "password",
        scope: 'public_profile', info_fields: 'id,name,link', display: 'popup', callback_path: '/stores/facebook_callback'

end
```